# How to use Graylog in python flask

Tags: python, flask, graylog

I'm trying to save the erros/info in graylog using python flask. I did something in my code. First, I imported the graylog using pip. then, I tried to config the graylog.But, I can't.

How could we config graylog in flask?

Comment: what did you try ? Show it in question (not in comment)

Comment: did you try to search `flask graylog` in Google. it seems there is flask extension to work with graylog.

Answer (score 3):

Use **graypy** for python

Python logging handlers that send messages in the Graylog Extended Log Format (GELF).

**Installation Using pip**

Install the basic graypy for python logging handlers

```
pip install graypy
```

some demo code -

```
import logging
import graypy
my_logger = logging.getLogger('test_logger')
my_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = graypy.GELFUDPHandler('localhost', 12201)
my_logger.addHandler(handler)
my_logger.debug('Hello Graylog2.')
```